# NumberFormatException when parsing an integer

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I have a file that contains lots of movie titles along with their years, rating out of 5 stars, and length. I'm attempting to read the file and store the titles, year, rating, and length as variables. The problem I've encountered is in my code for retrieving the year. The code compiles, but then upon running throws a NumberFormatException when it gets to a movie with multiple years (for example, it is listed as 2006-2009). Here is my code.

```
while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
                for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
                {

                    if(line.charAt(i) == ')' || line.charAt(i) == '-')//get year
                    {
                        yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
                        year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(year);

            }
```

Shouldn't `line.charAt(i) == '-'` in my if statement take care of this issue?

EDIT: The below code is where yearStart comes from.

```
if(line.charAt(i) == '(')//get title
                    {
                        title = line.substring(0,i);
                        yearStart = i+1;
                    }
```

The file is formatted like this: 
`title (year) | rating, length`
Sorry, I should have included that originally.

EDIT #2: Here's a sample of part of the file, if that helps

```
!Women Art Revolution (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 22m
#1 Cheerleader Camp (2010) |   3 stars, 1hr 35m
$5 a Day (2008) |   3.4 stars, 1hr 37m
'night, Mother (1986) |   3.7 stars, 1hr 36m
'Til Death (2006-2009) |   3.7 stars, 4 Seasons//This is the one that causes the error
@Suicide Room (2011) |   3.4 stars, 1hr 51m
... And God Spoke (1993) |   2.8 stars, 1hr 22m
```

Comment: May I suggest you to use a debugger and see what happens ?

Comment: Print out the line that you're trying to parse, or look at the exception stack trace to see what the code is in fact trying to parse. That will give you the problem and allow you to find the solution. In fact, post your stacktrace here with your question please.

Comment: What is the `yearStart`?

Comment: What is `yearStart`? It is of importance here but I don't see it being defined or initialized. (joval, jinx!)

Comment: Use Eclipse and find out exactly where the error is happening: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplersr1

Comment: @joval Sorry, I've edited my original post to include that information

Comment: @kviiri I've edited the original post to include that info

Comment: Thanks Austin, I'll have another look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens once you have found the year? The loop will still run until the end of the line, trying to parse things as numbers every time it finds a `)` or a `-`.

Maybe you should exit the loop once you have found the year.

```
                if(line.charAt(i) == ')' || line.charAt(i) == '-')//get year
                {
                    yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
                    break; // year found, no point in looping more
                }
```

Or maybe you should reset the `yearStart` index so that the second year can be parsed.

```
                if (line.charAt(i) == '-')
                {
                    // parse first year
                    yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
                    yearStart = i + 1; // reset to parse second year
                }
                else if (line.charAt(i) == ')')
                {
                    yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
                    year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
                    break; // year found
                }
```

Comment: Yup! This did it. Can't believe I didn't think of that lol. Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0):

Put Intger.parseInt in a try/catch block (similar to the one below) to see where this is failing and how:

```
try { 
  year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(
      "Failed to parse year '" + yr + "' in line '" + line + "'", e);
}
```

Btw: line.indexOf(')') returns the position of '(' in line.

Comment: "Failed to parse year '2006-2009' in line ''Til Death (2006-2009) |  3.7 stars, 4 seasons'

Comment: Looks like exactly what the other answer suggested. Or you are checking for the wrong character ('-' vs '–')?

Answer (score 0):

After the first year is found, `yearStart` is still at the index of the first year.  So when you try and get a `subString`, it is still `(2006-2009)` - Automatic `NumberFormatException`, can't parse the `-`.

You should change the `yearStart` after the first year is found:

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
{

    if(line.charAt(i) == ')' || line.charAt(i) == '-')//get year
    {
          yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
          year = Integer.parseInt(yr);
          yearStart = i + 1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `if(line.charAt(i) == ')' || line.charAt(i) == '-')` holds true twice in your loop. First, when the hyphen matches, and then, when the closing parenthesis matches. The first time, `year` is assigned to, in your example, `2009`. But then, the loop keeps running, and a few iterations later, you try to parse `"2005-2009"` which results in the NumberFormatException.

The most straightforward solution is to `break;` the loop just after assigning year, so that `year` is only assigned once. That said, supposing that you want to get the starting value of the interval.

A cleaner solution would be to avoid the loop at all, and instead judiciously using `String.indexOf`. Something like that (disclaimer: untested).

```
String title;
int year;

while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

    title = line.substring(0, line.indexOf('('));

    int yearStart = line.indexOf('(') + 1;
    int yearEnd;
    if (line.indexOf('-', yearStart) > 0 ) {
        yearEnd = line.indexOf('-', yearStart);
    } else {
        yearEnd = line.indexOf('(', yearEnd);
    }

    int yr = line.substring(yearStart,i);
    year = Integer.parseInt(yr);

    System.out.println(year);
}
```

Finally, a more professional solution would use [regular expresions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), I understand you might not be familiar with that, and thus I have tried to provide an answer that follows a similar structure as yours.

Comment: Now I am not sure if I correctly got your question. I assumed you wanted to get "2005" for a film whose year is "2005-2009". In case you want to get "2005" and then "2009", my code would not apply, although I would still recommend using indexOf